# Java Generics and Type

Tags: java, generics, types

I'm not sure if this is possible but if so it would help me out a lot:

Given:

```
public interface Foo<T> {

    public void onUpdate(T t);
}
```

If I have an instance of the a class that implements `Foo` is it possible for me to get the generic type?

```
public void someMethod(byte[] bytes) {
    /* 
     * this.bar implements Foo<ExampleType>
     *
     * I want to convert bytes to ExampleType using GSON but don't know the type.
     *
     * this.bar.onUpdate(...)
     */ 
}
```

Is it possible for me to get the generic type used when creating the instance of `this.bar`?

Comment: Short answer, no. If you need the type, you can add `Class<ExampleType> clazz` as an argument to `someMethod`.

Comment: @chrylis I didn't think so. I know what you are talking about but the methods are defined in an interface...

Comment: @chrylis yes I'd seen this... but also many others all with different responses. If this doesn't pick up any traction I'll delete this post.

Comment: @jjNford You can have the `Class<ExampleType>` instance passed in at construction time, rather than at the method.

Comment: @chrylis the object is constructed by the platform so I have no control over this.

Comment: http://www.gridshore.nl/2009/10/27/some-notes-on-discovering-your-type-parameter-using-the-reflection-api/

Answer (score 2):

*No* you cannot get the generic type in Java, that information is unavailable at runtime due to type erasure.

You can have separate interfaces for concrete types like,

```
interface FooExampleType extends Foo<ExampleType>{   

}
```

Also I would like to point out that after generifying the interface, if you are feeling the need to get the type of the generic argument then there is something wrong with the design of your code. If you follow proper polymorphic behavior in your code then after generifying you should not feel the need to get the type.

Comment: the design is fine. Its an abstract network wrapper (in a library project) and the data needs converted to the Generic type parameter. The application defines this generic type. I need the generic type token for GSON conversion.